# Unknown behavior on IEnumerable and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections, lazy-loading

When I convert ConcurrentBag to array and add condition ".Where(x => !x.IsDataLoaded)", I have unknown behavior on this collection.

```
 var all = rollings.ToArray();
 var copy = all
     .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
     .Where(x => !x.IsDataLoaded);
```

Next, I enumerate collection by foreach. Every iteration I logout debug info - copy.Count(), and this count decreased every iteration loop BUT I have NOT see "System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified"

```
foreach (var rolling in copy)
{
    ...
    rolling.IsDataLoaded = true;
    Log($"copy count: {copy.Count}");
}
```

So next I try copy.Max() but collection is empty and it throws exception:

```
DateTime beforeDatetime = DateTime.MinValue;
try
{
    beforeDatetime = copy.Max(x => x.To);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log(ex.ToString());
    Log($"copy count: {copy.Count}");
}
```

Does the LINQ work by lazy loading?
This will turn my life around.

[image: Code executing]

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are several problems, starting with `ConcurrentBag`. That's not a generic concurrent list, it's a specialized container using thread-local storage, making it cheap for the producing thread to read its own data and slow for others. Assuming your code is in a consumer thread, it will be slow. `Enumerable` isn't a container either, it represents an enumeration operation. `Count()`, `Any()`, `foreach` and `Max` execute the enumeration all over again. `Count`, `Max` and `foreach` iterate over everything 3 times

Comment: If you want a worker/subscriber thread to process data produced by other threads a *far* better option is to use a Channel, and process the items it produces one at a time asynchronously. Instead of trying to calculate the Count and Max from the original data, you can update them in the Channel-reading code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ is deferred execution. So it will not filter the data until you do something to force it to apply the filter (such as `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()` or running a `foreach` over it.)

So your `copy` is just setting up a filter on `all`, and that filter won't be applied until the `foreach (var rolling in copy)`. And since your are mutating the data in the underlying objects that LINQ is processing while it is processing it, the conditions for the filter are changing as it is trying to filter the data, so it will produce unexpected results.

You put that it works if you put a `.ToList()` at the end of setting up `copy`, which is because it is now at that point that you force the LINQ filter to be applied. i.e. before you start looping over it.

Your `try` block fails because you are re-applying the filter. The IDE (if you're using Visual Studio) usually puts a wavey underling (or that could be ReSharper doing that) under the second time you use copy to alert you to the fact that you're re-applying the filter and forcing the LINQ enumerable to be reevaluated as `.Max()` is another one of those methods that force the LINQ expression to be run. If you put the `.ToList()` when you create the `copy` then the filter is evaluated once at that point, your `copy` is a list whose contents don't change when you mutate the data in that list.

Comment: IMHO `…it will get confused` is explained poorly.

Comment: Fair point, I've changed it to "the conditions for the filter are changing as it is trying to filter the data."